# Use services of nestJS-modules in prisma seeds

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs, prisma, seeding

Any idea how to use nestJS-Services in seed.ts of prisma? I would like to build up a data-structure with related data by typing "prisma migrate reset". It works very well with the seeds-feature of prisma. But I think it's better (and faster) to use the CRUD-Operations that are already defined in the modules of nestJS than to write new code that does the same as the services. I'm not so familiar with the module-system in nestJS yet and how I can inject the services here.